# How to model the curly cable part of the phone

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves

[image]

Hello. I am a beginner in Blender. I started modeling this phone and when I got to the curly cable part it was a real challenge. Could someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are several solutions, here are 2. You could create it with a **Curve modifier** or with **Spline IK**. The second solution is bit more complicated but it will probably give a better result.

Also, I explain how to create bone controllers for each handle of your curve: it's useful when you want to animate or even keep a basic reset shape for your curve.

With a **Curve modifier**:

- Create your cable profile, it looks like a rectangle, shift it a bit from its origin. In *Object* mode apply the rotation of the object.
- Give it a *Screw* modifier, play with the parameters.

[image]

- Create a curve, flatten it, subdivide it a bit, make its origin begin at the same point as the cable origin, make sure its normals direction goes in the right direction, if not switch with <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*.
- Give your cable a *Curve* modifier, choose the curve as *Object*.
- Now if you bend the curve, the cable will follow.

[image]

- To give a bit more smoothness to your cable, bevel its profile vertices with a <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.
- Give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to the object.
- Now your cable is ready, you can apply the *Screw* modifier and parent the phone handset to the vertices of the cable end, or you can try to keep the *Screw* but I guess it will make the handset setting more complicated.
- To animate you can hook the curve handles to bones, as explained further, or to empties.

[image]

With bones and **Spline IK**, as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLONnEcaHgQ) by Peter Drakulic:

- You've made your object and your curve (see beginning of method 1). Apply the *Screw* and *Curve* modifiers of the object if you want. Keep the curve.
- Add a bone as long as the curve, subdivide it a bit.
- Keep your armature selected, switch to *Pose* mode and give the top bone a *Spline IK* constraint with the curve as *Target* and the number of bones as *Chain Length*. Deactivate the *Y Stretch* option. Now when you move the curve the bones follow.
- Parent the object to the armature *With Automatic Weight*. Put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subsurf*. Activate the *Preserve Volume* option of the *Armature* modifier.
- Again, to animate you can hook the curve handles to bones.

[image]

You may want to **create some bone controllers** for each handle:

- Create a new armature with each bones at the exact same point as each handle.
- Switch the armature to *Pose* mode.
- Select one of the bones.
- Press <kbd>shift</kbd> and select the curve.
- Go in *Edit* mode and select the corresponding handle.
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook To Selected Object Bone*.
- Same thing for the other bones.
- Now you can control the whole curve with this armature.

[image]

Comment: this solution has a flaw, if the curve angle is too strong it will deform the cable a little bit too much (reduces its height), which is not realistic, there's another solution, with bones and Spline IK, but it's much more tedious: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLONnEcaHgQ

Comment: Spline IK, adding bones to the curve to reduce the amount of bending. I read about it once.

Comment: @moonboots it might be worth turning your comment into a full-blown answer with a couple screenshots and a bit of text to grab yourself those sweet sweet answer points.

Comment: It would also benefit those who can't watch YouTube in whatever place they are. \*stares in disbelief at his hospital's network filters\*

Comment: Okay, edited again, the second solution is indeed more realist, you just need to deactivate the Y Stretch option in the Spline IK constraint   ;)

Comment: UV,, I was waiting for the Spline iK :) ..[Bendy Bones](https://vimeo.com/181807778) would also be a tidy solution? There's a follow up tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4EOssQWVP0). You probably wouldn't want to extend what is already a nice answer.. (If you don't want to spend too much time on chickens, see the second link first)

Comment: oh yes of course Stretch To constraint, I'm going to test  ;)

Comment: interesting but it looks like it can only works fine with the Skin modifier, so you can't really control the profile