# Advanced method to create a rig for a realistic metal chain? (don't need physic)

Tags: python, rigging

[image]

I want to create a chain rig, and the Array+Curve modifier usual method is not ideal for my project since it deforms the geometry of the chain on sharp corners. Ideally  I'd like a solution similar to this but without deformation.

I'm thinking about using bones and the "Follow path" bone constrain, and assign a ring to each bones. This needs to be done through a script to be practical. Problem is I'd need to get the curve length through code and I have no idea how to do that, but since the curve modifier need this information to work there is probably a way to retrieve that with Python.

Second problem would be distributing the right amount of bones to the curve (based on length and scale of the ring).

At the end of the day the rig needs to be pretty fast to work with, a curve is ideal even if the tilting freaks out when manipulating the starting point (which can be annoying but I'm ok with that).

Any ideas to explore?

Edit: I'm also interested in a good solution for binding all the individual rings to individual bones rapidly (probably with a script). Also 1 every 2 rings need to be slightly rotated so it doesn't overlap with the one adjacent to it (if that make sense, see image below since it's what I've done).

Comment: Would a [IK Spline](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/posing/bone_constraints/inverse_kinematics/spline_ik.html) be helpful?

Comment: Yes! That looks really promising actually :)

Comment: I'll mark this as a duplicate since a metall chain and a phone cord are somewhat similiar, and the linked answer is very good. Feel free to object or confirm my hint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to model the curly cable part of the phone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139523/how-to-model-the-curly-cable-part-of-the-phone)

Comment: Although this post is nice the process for creating and binding a metal chain is very different since it's made of individual parts that are not suppose to be deformed but only moved and rotated individually. I'd rather not mark it as duplicated to stay open to an hypothetical solution more adapted to a metal chain.