# Creating a spiral along a bezier path

Tags: bezier-curves, procedural

How can I create a spiral that follows an arbitrary bezier path?

Here's an example of this in Fusion 360:[image: Example of goal]
So, in other words, this is a bezier curve that winds itself around another bezier curve to produce a spiral. The spiral profile, climb angle, and distance from the central bezier curve should all be customizable.

Comment: Enable the "Add Curve: Extra Objects" addon to create spirals easily in the add object menu and add a curve modifier to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave a detailed answer about a phone cable [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139523/how-to-model-the-curly-cable-part-of-the-phone). If you want to keep a curve instead of a mesh you can do it the way below. At the end you can convert your curve to mesh if you want. I'm not sure you can use 2 curves and array a mesh along the spiral though. So:

- Create a spiral.

[image]
[image]

- Create another curve, a straight one this time. Give your spiral a *Curve* modifier with the second curve as *Object*.

[image]

- Select your spiral. In the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Shape* > Choose *Fill* > *Full*, and in *Geometry* play with the *Bevel Depth* and *Resolution* values.

[image]

- Move the straight curve, the spiral will bend.

[image]