# Regain Blender Parameters Menu

Tags: bezier-curves

This question should apply to functions besides "Add Spiral", but this is just what I'm working on at the moment. In my example picture, I created an Archimedan spiral (Add > Curve > Curve Spirals > Archimedan) and rotated/scaled in on Object View to make it better fit the ponytail. Later I realized that I still needed to adjust one of the options originally present on the spiral's options menu (Radius Growth), but that menu is gone now. (It disappeared again when on another attempt, I made a curved line and fit the spiral to that via [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157053/creating-a-spiral-along-a-bezier-path).) Is there a way to recover that options menu without having to make a new shape? Alternatively (and this one WOULD be specific to my project), can I preview the spiral fit to that curve without losing that menu in the first place?

[image: example picture]

---

**UPDATE**: I'm running Blender 2.79b, and in attempting to follow Susu's answer, I find that the key parameters are missing (which is what required me to perform object transforms in the first place). Not sure how to recover those. (I also have an issue with the spiral's bezier shape not laying flush with the ponytail surface, but that one probably needs a new question.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

You can't go back to the creation parameters once you've made any transformation (rotate/scale).

Solution:

Delete the spiral, make a new one and use the parameter's options to place and rotate the spiral.[image]

Comment: I'm on Blender 2.79b and when I went to remake the spiral, I don't see those boxed options... Just everything above the 2D/3D option, excluding that option. Clicking Spiral Curve right under Presets says "missing paths"; I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: I've updated my original post with a screenshot showing the new problem. My parameters menu lacks Location and Rotation fields.

Comment: Maybe it is time to update to a newer version.

Comment: My ability to update may be limited by a crucial plugin's upwards compatibility (I export to MikuMikuDance, a Japanese animation program), but I do at least see that it's compatible with 2.83. Is it the individual plugin-maker's responsibility to maintain upwards compatibility (expected answer), or does Blender keep backwards compatibility for user-made plugins?

Comment: New questions should be asked in new posts, not in comments.