# Spiral wrap around hydraulic hose

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make spiral wraps for my machine kind of like the ones in the picture.

The spiral wrap is around hydraulic hoses that moves so the spiral wrap need to deform with the hoses. I have got the hydraulic hose figured out but I can't find the solution for the spiral wrap. Is there a relatively easy solution to this? I potentially have to make a lot of these.

[image: Spiral hose wrap]

Anyone else who have had the same problem? I'm thinking there must be someone else who have had the same challenge but I cant find anything wilts searching online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139523/how-to-model-the-curly-cable-part-of-the-phone https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157053/creating-a-spiral-along-a-bezier-path/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166252/animating-rocking-horse-with-a-spring-base/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282515/how-to-make-braided-tubing/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to find any of these when I searched, but I'm new to finding things to this site so I'm not quite sure how and for what to search for.