# Spiral Hair Tie

Tags: modeling

I have used a screw modifier on a curve. the problem I am having is that on the inside of the curve, the coils should touch, yet not compress. Here, the coils compress and they don't touch. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Hair ties]

Comment: if it's supposed to be animated you could do it through Spline IK: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139523/how-to-model-the-curly-cable-part-of-the-phone/139524#139524 ... otherwise you could correct manually, but actually what you show is different than your reference image (completely circular)